# Kartik DEST_FILE yii2

Tags: yii2-basic-app

Please I am having a problem trying to save a generated pdf file to a tmp folder using Kartik.
I have used the code but nothing seems to work, this a snippet of my code.
Thanks.

```
$content = $this->renderPartial('sertifikat', [
    'model' => $model,
    'bal' => $bal,
    'derece' => $derece,
]);

// setup kartik\mpdf\Pdf component
$pdf = new Pdf([
    // set to use core fonts only
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,

    // A4 paper format
    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,

    // portrait orientation
    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,

    // stream to browser inline
    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_FILE,
    'filename' => Url::to(['generate/report']),
    'tempPath' => '/generatedFolder',

    // your html content input
    'content' => $content,

    // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
    // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting
    'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',

    // any css to be embedded if required
    'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}',

    // set mPDF properties on the fly
    'options' => ['title' => 'Krajee Report Title'],

    // call mPDF methods on the fly
    'methods' => [
        'SetHeader'=>['Krajee Report Header'],
        'SetFooter'=>['{PAGENO}'],
    ]
]);

// return the pdf output as per the destination setting
return $pdf->render();
```

Comment: Please read this guide on asking to prevent down votes and receive more answers: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You need to explain how your code works and what error you're getting to help potential answerers to answer.

Comment: Clean up formatting.

Comment: Thanks CrazyPython, well i dont know how to go about saving the generated pdf to the tempPath using kartik's mpdf. i dont intend saving using the default format which is Yii::$app->getAlias('@app/runtime/mpdf')

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`filename` should be a string, the output PDF filename (may include a path).

---

YOUR MISTAKE IS

```
'filename' => Url::to(['generate/report']),
```

CHANGE TO

```
path/to/filename.pdf
```